# ActiveRecord retrieval with order on Sql Server throws ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby, sql-server, activerecord

I'm in a ruby world, using activerecord (3.2.11), tiny_tds (0.5.1-x86-mingw32) and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.10).

The following works:

```
require 'active_record'  
class My_Table < ActiveRecord::Base; end  
My_Table.establish_connection connection_hash  
My_Table.first
```

The following throws a ConnectionNotEstablished *in the same session*:

```
require 'active_record'  
class My_Table < ActiveRecord::Base; end  
My_Table.establish_connection connection_hash  
My_Table.order(:some_column).first
```

As a workaround, I'm pulling *all* such records and sorting in ruby, but this is obviously wrong. I'm missing something obvious; what is it?

Comment: Actually, (a) I'm a bit of a rooby noob, and (b) the order clause throws the exception regardless of how/where I code it.

Comment: Further: I notice ConnectionHandler#retrieve_connection is passed My_Table for the first example, but ActiveRecord::Base for the second.

Comment: If I establish_connection on AR::Base, the order clause works. What's going on?

Comment: Ahhhh; the example was misleading. I'm querying/manipulating multiple tables dynamically (because I don't know their names ahead of time); changing My_Table.table_name appears to kill the ability to order().